# OneNote Graph API: Get order of sections

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote-api

When working with OneNote data using the Microsoft Graph API, is there a way to get the sort order of sections? For pages, one can use `?pagelevel=true&$orderby=order` to get the page order and level and also sort by the page order. But it seems there's no equivalent for sections…

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately we don't support section order in the OneNote Graph API yet. This is in our backlog and will let you know once it's available

Answer (score 0):

I happen to have the same problem. There are two different ways I suspect to be available. That's replaying corrected POST requests from a web browser to (in my case) https://euc-onenote.officeapps.live.com/o/OneNote.ashx where a list of section IDs is transferred in a specific order in a JSON object to edit the order. (You get a sample request by recording http requests when changing the order of sections using drag and drop in the OneNote WebApp)
The other way might be to work with OneNote 2016 and PowerShell or vbs, where you can work with a comObject.
Both not very satisfying to me, but possible to solve...